# R Shiny selectInput and submitButton side by side

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, submit-button

I am working on a Shiny app in R.  The app is run by shiny server running on linux.

I need to create a side by side selectInput field and submitButton.  I made the following attempt.

#### from my ui.r

```
div(style="display:inline-block",
    selectInput("input$GeneVariable4", 
                label = h4(""), 
                choices = (Choices_cd), 
                multiple = TRUE,
                selected = c("Slc26a5","Sri"),
                selectize = TRUE,
                width = '400px'
                )
),
div(style="display:inline-block",
    submitButton("Submit")
),
```

This code generates the following result

[image: [img]https://i.imgur.com/3bXcrR8m.png[/img]]

The problem with this is that there is a slight offset between the selectInput field and the submitButton.  It is ugly and I hate it.

Does anyone know how i might solve this issue.  I have tried adding `br(),` spaces but it just shifts the offset up or down and doesn't eliminate it.

Any advice on how to get these side by side would be much appreciated. Additionally the submit button cant be placed below because the selectInput drops down with choices when selected, obscuring any submit button placed underneath the bar.

Comment: Change your style and put a margin there.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `fluidRow` and `column`

```
fluidRow(column(4,
            selectInput(
                "input$GeneVariable4",
                label = h4(""),
                choices = (Choices_cd),
                multiple = TRUE,
                selected = c("Slc26a5", "Sri"),
                selectize = TRUE,
                width = '400px'
              )
            ),
     column(4, offset = 1,
                submitButton("Submit")))
```